# Random Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, trust

I know this might seem like a duplicate, and I have read the other posts with this problem, but my scenario is different in that it happens at a random time during the course of the day, and then gets resolved when I recycle the IIS App Pool.

It happens even when I have this proposed workaround in place:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

It is an ASP.Net MVC 5 app on .Net FW 4.7.  At some random point calls to 3rd party https API's just stop working, returning the said error, and continue returning that error until I recycle the IIS App Pool.

Please advise on what can be causing this?

Comment: Is there a proxy in between? Maybe you didn't even know about it before?

Comment: Maybe your 3rd party code sometimes overrides `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`? This should be easy to check.

Comment: @Zergatul It's my own code that's calling 3rd party HTTPS API's.  My own code is definitely not overriding my own setting of the ServerCertificateValidationCallback.  In fact, I only had the callback in there for a day or two to check if the problem gets resolved.  But it made no difference.

Comment: @PepitoSh How can I check this?  The app is running on a cloud-hosted VM, so that is a possibility.  But how can I make sure?  And if so, what do I do about it?  Can that lead to the behaviour I am experiencing?

Comment: Well, it was just a wild guess. I live in China and we experienced similar behavior and nothing really helped, other than overhauling the communication with the assumption that it may break anytime. Maybe recycling the IIS app pool is too strong, you could just get more strict with the 3rd party connection.

Comment: @PepitoSh Sorry for sounding dumb...what would an example be of "get more strict" be?

Comment: Maybe wrong working, sorry. We reestablished the connection every time and didn't leave it open. We could do it due to the frequency of calls. I think once a minute it could be reestablished.